# ¿Cómo actualizar página web en servidor xampp?

Tags: xampp

Ayuda, Estoy haciendo una página web y la tengo en un servidor local xampp, al momento de ingresar al localhost me aparece mi página pero la versión antigua. En la carpeta htdocs agregue los archivos nuevos de mi página, está todo actualizado pero aún así no se ven en el localhost. ¿Cómo actualizo mi página?

Comment: Probaste control+f5 en el navegador?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba borrando el cache con:

```
control+shift+R
```

Puedes tambien abrir tu consola del navegador (**F12**) e irte a network y pulsar alli (**F5**) para actualizar los componentes

Tambien estando en consola pulsa (**elements**) y podras ver los archivos que estan en ese momento siendo mostrados asi verificas si se estan cargando bien

Comment: Solucionado!! Muchas gracias Victor, me ayudó mucho tu respuesta. Saludos

Comment: @MeriiC jejejej pase por lo mismo y sufri demasiado, algunas veces puede que no actualice cuando tengas algun error en los archivos javascript

Comment: ok, gracias igual. xD

Answer (score 0):

puede pasar que estes viendo un cache de tu browser, fijate de ingresar en modo desarrollo desde el browser.O tambien puede pasar que la pagina que estas armando tiene parte "compilada" como laravel y te genera algo así "core\storage\framework\views\b05f124bdd7a18c312dc3c63a872f2cab837c400.php", espero que te sirva de ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Nico, lo solucioné. Saludos